# How do I use a data constructor on a value wrapped inside an IO monad?

Tags: haskell

So I have a data type in haskell defined as follows:

```
import qualified Data.UUID as UUID
import qualified Data.Time.Clock as CLK

data MyRecord = MyRecord {
    id :: UUID.UUID,
    creationDate :: CLK.UTCTime,
    comment :: String
}
```

now the problem is that the UUID and UTCTime are returned inside an IO monad. The functions I use to generate them have the following type

for UUID

```
nextRandom :: IO uuid-types-1.0.3:Data.UUID.Types.Internal.UUID
```

for getting the current time stamp:

```
getCurrentTime :: IO UTCTime
```

my problem is how do use the data constructor to actually initialise the data type?

I can do the following

```
MyRecord <$> nextRandom
```

and this works, but I am not able to understand how to provide the constructor with the other argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *sequential application* [**`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-) for this. For example:

```
MyRecord <$> nextRandom <*> getCurrentTime <*> return "some comment"
```

This is equivalent to:

```
some_function :: IO MyRecord
some_function = do
    r <- nextRandom
    t <- getCurrentTime
    return (MyRecord r t "some comment")
```

What here basically happens is that if you write:

```
MyRecord <$> nextRandom
```

you construct an item of type `IO (UTCTime -> String -> MyRecord)`. Now by using the `(<*>)` function with as left operand this function, and as right operand an `IO UTCTime`, we thus construct an object of type `IO (String -> MyRecord)`.

We can use [**`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) or [**`pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure) to convert a `String` to an `IO String`, and we thus use again `(<*>)` to apply this to the partial data constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This is the common [applicative style pattern](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors):

```hs
MyRecord <$> nextRandom
         <*> getCurrentTime
         <*> pure "my comment"
```